# ios sqlite3_open fails the 50th time that is called

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, database-connection

I have a strange problem, I hope to fix:

here is my code:

```
-(Shot*) getShot:(int)shot {
    NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM tbShots where nShot = %d ", shot];
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentFolderPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbFilePath = [documentFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATABASE_NAME_EXT];

    if (dbFilePath == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"dbFilePath is NULL");
    }

    sqlite3 *dbHandle;
    if (sqlite3_open([dbFilePath UTF8String], &dbHandle)) {
        NSLog(@"sqlite3_open: failed");
    }

    sqlite3_stmt *preparedStatement;
    const char* queryStatement = [sqlStr UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbHandle, queryStatement, -1, &preparedStatement, NULL);

    Shot *s = nil;
    NSString * note = @"";
    while( sqlite3_step(preparedStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        s = [[[Shot alloc] initWithShot:shot] autorelease];
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(preparedStatement);
    sqlite3_close(dbHandle);    
    return s;
}
```

and seems to works fine now: but I have a problem:

I call this functon many times and when I call it the 50th time, the sqlite3_open function fails (I see the log error 'sqlite3_open: failed'...

I made some error?
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post errorcode NSLog(@"Failed to open database with error %s",sqlite3_errmsg(dbHandle));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue - To resolve it you have to open the DB when the app start and close the DB when the user leave the app. YOU SHOULD NOT OPEN AND CLOSE THE DB FOR EACH QUERY!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Hi @ghiboz I used to have the same issue try this ,  I solved my issue :)

```
- (NSMutableArray *) SELECT_LANES_IN_POSITIONS:(NSString *)lanes{

sqlite3 *db;

const char *path = [[self getDBPathiPhone] UTF8String];

int v_Open = sqlite3_open(path, &db);

if(v_Open == SQLITE_OK){

    NSString *sqlS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"THE SQL STATEMENT" , Some];

    const char *sql = [sqlS cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    int v_prepare = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);

    if(v_prepare == SQLITE_OK){

        while ((sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {

        } 

    }else{

        NSLog(@"FAIL :: SELECT :: %i", v_prepare);

    }

    sqlite3_reset(stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

}else{

    NSLog(@"FAIL :: OPEN :: %i", v_Open);
}

sqlite3_close(db);

return nil;


}
```